# Handling dependency injections

Tags: go, dependency-injection, refactoring

let's say I have following code:

```golang
import (
   handlerA "some/path/handlerA"
   handlerB "some/path/handlerB"
   handlerC "some/path/handlerC"
   handlerD "some/path/handlerD"
   ....
   handlerZ "some/path/handlerZ"
)

func DoSomething(a handlerA.A, b handlerB.B, c handlerC.C, d handlerD.D..., z handlerZ.Z) {
   a.DoA()
   b.DoB()
   c.DoC()
   d.DoD()
   ....
   z.DoZ()
}
```

I obviously made the function `DoSomething(...)` mockable, as this makes my function unit testable. But because of that I get way to many arguments because of all the dependencies my function needs to get injected.

Is there a better way in Golang to handle many dependencies?

Comment: This looks more like a design issue. Having that many dependencies is a code smell and indicates that the function may be doing too much. Some of those dependencies may need to be aggregated into a service.

Comment: I exaggerated on purpose. I would never code something like that. But having functions with two or three dependency injection arguments are quite common I would say. Especially if you don't got enough time for refactoring code because of deadlines or something like that.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo which is a dependency injection framework for golang

Comment: Or https://github.com/google/wire which is first-party, though not part of the stdlib.

Comment: What is the difference between `.DoA()` and `.DoB()`? They both could be just `.Do()`. Now it is possible to define an interface like `type Doer interface { Do() }` and the signature can change to `DoSomething(...Doer)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle many injections would be to use a struct as wrapper:

```golang
type SomethingDoer struct {
  a handlerA.A,
  b handlerB.B,
  c handlerC.C,
  d handlerD.D,
  ...
  z handlerZ.Z,
}

func (sd SomethingDoer) DoSomething() {
   sd.a.DoA()
   sd.b.DoB()
   sd.c.DoC()
   sd.d.DoD()
   ....
   sd.z.DoZ()
}
```

I just figured that out by reading the question by myself again...

Comment: This doesn't reduces the dependencies, it just groups them into a struct. Having to provide a struct value, you also need to initialize it with the same dependencies.

Comment: Yes, but in that way I would avoid having to many parameters in functions, which would make the code more readable I guess. Also imagine if one would need to call this function on multiple occasions: With the wrapper you only would need to inject dependencies once.